# jasypt EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer not helping in decrypting the password

Tags: spring, jasypt

I started doing some examples using Jasypt and Spring and unfortunately, could not test the decryption successfully.

I'm using Spring 4.3.15 and Jasypt 1.9.3. I think I followed the examples given in the internet carefully, but still see the password is sent encrypted only.

My spring configuration looks like below

```
<bean id="mydatasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="encryptedPropertyPlaceHolder" class=**"org.jasypt.spring4.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"**>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
            <property name="config">
                <bean class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
                    <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
                    ***<!-- <property name="passwordEnvName" value="APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" /> -->***
                    <property name="password" value="jasypt" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>   
</bean>
```

and jdbc.properties has values

```
jdbc.url=<<some url>>
jdbc.username=<<some username>>
jdbc.password=ENC(Y3EEFmt5lEAC96GJlzK9VcETH)
```

When I ran my testcase, which uses mydatasource as Autowired, I see that password field is set as **ENC(Y3EEFmt5lEAC96GJlzK9VcETH)**. Other fields are properly assigned using propertyConfigurer. But the encrypted password is not decrypted before assigning to datasource.

I'm not sure, what is that I'm missing here ?

Also, as you noticed I used hard coded password in encryptedPropertyPlaceHolder. I have read about  APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD, but when trying to set the value using VM arguments in my eclipse as -DAPP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD=jasypt, it is not working.

Comment: I also tried replacing <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" /> with <property name="password" value="ENC(Y3EEFmt5lEAC96GJlzK9VcETH)" />. Still did not work.

Comment: Remove the`propertyConfigurer`, the first one that has a property will replace it, with this configuration you basically disable jasypt.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, by removing propertyconfigurer, how can I replace the non encrypted fields, like the one that does not start with ENC().

Comment: That is done by the same `EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. It is an extension of the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` which automatically decrypts values starting with `ENC()`, others will be injected as-is.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But not sure what I'm doing wrong. But some time the decryption works and some times fails with padding error. I may have to try again. I will update my findings in this post.